# A query with a reverse LIKE condition

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

There is a table with column name "phone" and has different numbers in different formats.

Example:

```
id | number
1  | 03439879098
2  | 01109890032
3  | +91 932 3233237
```

Now if I want to search "3233237" then the query will be:

```
select * from table where number like '%3233237%';
```

Result will be:

```
id | number
3  | +91 932 3233237
```

But in my case I want the reverse

```
String search = "+92 343 9879098"

select * from table where number like search
```

The result should be:

```
id | number
1  | 03439879098
```

Because the column *number* and search string has a common string, which is **9879098**.

**Query should be designed in such a way that it looks for a record that both search string and column value has a common sub string**

Kindly give me some idea.

Comment: What about the spaces? Which parts of the number should match, and which can be different? You are asking to find values that are *somewhat similar*, and that is not well defined.

Comment: Just delete "+92" from the search `String`

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What is 'name' ?

Comment: What about the number "98790985", it contains part of the string. Should it match? Or just the last digits? Please edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a tricky one. You can do it in pure SQL executing:

```
select * from table where '+92 343 9879098' like '%' || number || '%';
```

Here we're concatenating the **number** column with the wildcards **%**.

*Also You could resolve it programatically:

```
    String search = "+92 343 9879098";
    String query = "select * from table where ";
    String[] parts = search.split( "\\s+" );
    for ( String oneNumber : parts ) {
        query += " number like '%" +oneNumber+ "%' OR";
    }
    query += " false"; // this, or trim the last OR calculating the string length
```

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `NOT LIKE` so it'd be something like

`select * from table where name not like search`

Comment: While his title asks for a reverse function, the details in his question do not.